# mixed logit model estimation problem in R, always same as initial values

Tags: r, mixed-models

The thing is,I have a wide form dataset with missing values, and the response variable is binary, YES OR NO for the response. I need to estimate it by mixed logit model, so I firstly impute the data by mice package. After that, transfer the data into mlogit.data class, do estimation by gmnl. **The estimate values result is always nearly the same as the initial values....This seems to result from the gradient is close to 0 so no optimization at all.**

I use another simpler data from a homework(So it's not the problem of data I think) to check how it goes. The weird thing is, I delete some values of it, do imputation, estimation, same result, which means there may be something wrong in the imputation? But using the original dataset without missing values gives same result. In this case, I just read data, transfer it to mlogit class, do estimation, all by in-built functions in R. What can be wrong? I'm totally confused and desperate now.

Is there someone help me on this? I appreciate any help and discussion.

**The simple data looks like:**
[the missing one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfaJQ.png)

The code is:

```
# use data having missing values
data1   <- read.table("train_Titanic.csv", sep = ",", header = T) 

data1$Pclass <- as.factor(data1$Pclass)
data1$Male <- as.logical(data1$Male)
data1$SibSp <- as.factor(data1$SibSp)
data1$Parch <- as.factor(data1$Parch)

part <- data1[,3:8]
imputed <- mice(part,m=7,maxit = 2)
part2 <- complete(imputed,1)
data_imputed <- cbind(data1[,1:2],part2)

data_imputed <- na.exclude(data_imputed) # drop the data without response
reg_missing <- mlogit.data(data_imputed,choice = "Survived",shape = "wide",id.var = "PassengerId")
model_missing <- gmnl(Survived ~ Pclass+Male+SibSp+Parch+Age+Fare
              | 1,
              data = reg_missing,
              model = "mixl", 
              reflevel = 2, 
              haltons = NA, 
              R = 150, 
              panel = TRUE,
              print.init = TRUE, 
              print.level = 2,
              ranp = c(Age = "n"),
              correlation = FALSE,
              iterlim = 500,
              method = "bhhh",)

# use the original data having no missing values
data2 <- read.table("train_Titanic(1).csv", sep = ",", header = T) # Load whole data
reg_nomissing <- mlogit.data(data2,choice = "Survived",shape = "wide",id.var = "PassengerId")
model_nomissing <- gmnl(Survived ~ Pclass+Male+SibSp+Parch+Age+Fare
                    | 1,
                    data = reg_nomissing,
                    model = "mixl", 
                    reflevel = 2, 
                    haltons = NA, 
                    R = 150, 
                    panel = TRUE,
                    print.init = TRUE, 
                    print.level = 2,
                    ranp = c(Age = "n"),
                    correlation = FALSE,
                    iterlim = 500,
                    method = "bhhh")
```

The output for model_nomissing is(the first one is similar):

```
Starting Values:
0:(intercept)        Pclass          Male         SibSp         Parch          Fare           Age        sd.Age 
   0.37776251   -0.03504190   -0.01583640   -0.01261044   -0.01048478   -0.74403561   -0.49059713    0.10000000 
Estimating MIXL model 
----- Initial parameters: -----
fcn value: -405.3734 
                parameter initial gradient free
0:(intercept)  0.37776251     4.710893e-11    1
Pclass        -0.03504190     2.170486e-14    1
Male          -0.01583640     4.385381e-15    1
SibSp         -0.01261044     5.162537e-15    1
Parch         -0.01048478     5.884182e-15    1
Fare          -0.74403561     5.500045e-13    1
Age           -0.49059713     1.878497e-13    1
sd.Age         0.10000000    -6.589781e-16    1
Condition number of the (active) hessian: 2.489843e+32 
-----Iteration 1 -----
--------------
gradient close to zero 
1  iterations
estimate: 0.3777625 -0.0350419 -0.0158364 -0.01261044 -0.01048478 -0.7440356 -0.4905971 0.1 
Function value: -405.3734
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I just find I do something wrong, I should create Wide Panel Data from Wide Format, make attributes like A1 have A1.1, A1.2.

But the problem still exists, final values are same as the initials.